# Increasing ember server build times

Tags: ember.js

While running ember server locally during development sessions I see increasing build times with successive changes. The build times get to a point where I have to kill ember server with 'kill -9' (as 'ctrl-c' seems to be ignored) because the server daemon no longer reacts to file changes or responds to http requests. I've been limping along like this, but I can't imagine this is expect behavior since its slows the development process significantly.

Here are my environment details:

- OSX 10.10.4
- Ember 1.13.6
- Node 0.12.7
- Watchman: 3.3.0
- Hardware: 2.2Ghz intel core i7, 16GB RAM

My application currently consists of:

- 8 js files, totaling 600 lines of code
- 5 hbs templates, totaling 150 lines of handlebars markup
- 1 scss stylesheet, totaling 64 lines of sass markup

Changes to the style sheet and template files appear to have the most significant impact on the builds times.

What follows is an example of the build times that I'm seeing:

```
Build successful - 11516ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Test Support CSS                      | 2321ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles                         | 2044ms              
Concat: Test Support JS                       | 1865ms              
Concat: Vendor                                | 1864ms              
SassCompiler                                  | 1836ms              
Funnel: App JS Files                          | 905ms               

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Test Support CSS (1)                  | 2321ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles (1)                     | 2044ms              
Concat: Test Support JS (1)                   | 1865ms              
Concat: Vendor (1)                            | 1864ms              
SassCompiler (1)                              | 1836ms              
Funnel: App JS Files (1)                      | 905ms               

file changed controllers/signin.js

Build successful - 13390ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Test Support CSS                      | 2656ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles                         | 2330ms              
Concat: Vendor                                | 2185ms              
SassCompiler                                  | 2103ms              
Concat: Test Support JS                       | 1817ms              
Funnel: App JS Files                          | 1649ms              

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Test Support CSS (1)                  | 2656ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles (1)                     | 2330ms              
Concat: Vendor (1)                            | 2185ms              
SassCompiler (1)                              | 2103ms              
Concat: Test Support JS (1)                   | 1817ms              
Funnel: App JS Files (1)                      | 1649ms              

file changed templates/signin.hbs

Build successful - 12833ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Vendor                                | 2779ms              
SassCompiler                                  | 2442ms              
Concat: Test Support JS                       | 2225ms              
Concat: Test Support CSS                      | 2036ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles                         | 1661ms              
Funnel: App JS Files                          | 1064ms              

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Vendor (1)                            | 2779ms              
SassCompiler (1)                              | 2442ms              
Concat: Test Support JS (1)                   | 2225ms              
Concat: Test Support CSS (1)                  | 2036ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles (1)                     | 1661ms              
Funnel: App JS Files (1)                      | 1064ms              

file changed controllers/signin.js

Build successful - 15537ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Test Support JS                       | 2893ms              
Concat: Test Support CSS                      | 2844ms              
Concat: Vendor                                | 2700ms              
SassCompiler                                  | 2653ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles                         | 2282ms              
Funnel: App JS Files                          | 1203ms              

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Concat: Test Support JS (1)                   | 2893ms              
Concat: Test Support CSS (1)                  | 2844ms              
Concat: Vendor (1)                            | 2700ms              
SassCompiler (1)                              | 2653ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles (1)                     | 2282ms              
Funnel: App JS Files (1)                      | 1203ms              

file changed controllers/signin.js

Build successful - 17364ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
SassCompiler                                  | 3667ms              
Concat: Test Support CSS                      | 3643ms              
Concat: Vendor                                | 3262ms              
Concat: Test Support JS                       | 2437ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles                         | 2408ms              
Funnel: App JS Files                          | 999ms               

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
SassCompiler (1)                              | 3667ms              
Concat: Test Support CSS (1)                  | 3643ms              
Concat: Vendor (1)                            | 3262ms              
Concat: Test Support JS (1)                   | 2437ms              
Concat: Vendor Styles (1)                     | 2408ms              
Funnel: App JS Files (1)

                  | 999ms
```

Comment: I'd probably raise this as an issue with broccoli or ember cli on github

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue I was experiencing was resolved in the most recent version of ember-cli.  Upgrading to ember-cli 1.13.8, following the instructions [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#upgrading) yielded an order of magnitude speed up in builds with consistent build times across successive edits.